# Printing the Array Length with 'fn' in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am new to jsp and jstl technology. I am trying to print out a some text in `<c:out value>`,  please see point 1 in code. I am trying to display a text like this -

```
Account Manager-5
```

Here `${aStageRole.displayName} = 'Account Manager'`
     and (`pro.stageRoles`) is an array which length is `5`.

```
<select id="selectRole<%=i %>" onchange="javascript:selectRole('selectRole<%=i %>')">
    <c:forEach items="${pro.stageRoles}" var="aStageRole" varStatus="status">
        <option value="${aStageRole.role.id}"> <c:out value="${aStageRole.displayName}-{fn:length(pro.stageRoles)}"/></option>  //1
    </c:forEach>                
</select>
```

But the code outputs the following value in the dropdown -

```
Account Manager-{fn:length(pro.stageRoles)}
```

Can anyone help me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You could try using value="${aStageRole.displayName + "-" + fn:length(pro.stageRoles)}"

Answer (score 0):

Expressions in JSTL are enclosed by `${}`. The part of code `{fn:length(pro.stageRoles)}` is not evaluated as JSP EL without $ sign.

```jsp
${fn:length(pro.stageRoles)}
```